# astropy.io.votable - Is there an easy way to get VOTable PARAMeters?

Tags: python, astropy

I have a lot of VO tables like this one:

> http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps3/fps.php?ID=2MASS/2MASS.H

but I am not actually interested in the tables themselves, only in the metadata a.k.a. [PARAMeters](http://www.ivoa.net/documents/REC/VOTable/VOTable-20040811.html#ToC24). 
Is there an easy way to get these (as there is for FITS table headers) in python/astropy?

The only thing I found was some nested for-loop:

```
from astropy.table import Table
H = Table.read('2MASS.2MASS.H.xml')

for resource in H.resources:
    for param in resource.params:
        print param.name, param.value
```

EDIT: What I actually want is to get a list/dict of PARAM *value* and a list of corresponding PARAM *names*...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `iter_fields_and_params` to iterate over all `FIELD` and `PARAM` tags in the file.  In VOTable land, the only difference between a `FIELD` and a `PARAM` is that a `PARAM` has a constant value, so these are logically grouped together.

Comment: Thanks Michael! But how do I then actually access the "generator object" that iter_fields_and_params produces? `**AttributeError**: 'generator' object has no attribute 'name'`. Sorry, this is all really new to me..

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Accessing each of the individual PARAM *values* is easy. E.g.:

```
print H.get_field_by_id('filterID').value
```

Although this is not entirely clear from the astropy docs, accessing the PARAM *values* (once you know the PARAM names) works exactly in the same fashion as for FIELDs...